# SQL column type mismatch error

Tags: mysql, sql, manifold

Any idea why I'm getting a 'column type mismatch [Analysis.ASCo]' here? The cursor highlights the second 'Analysis' in line 5.

```
select
[Analysis].[Project],
[Analysis].[Borehole],
[Analysis].[Depth],
([Analysis].[ASCu]+(([Analysis].[ASCo]*30500)/5630)) as [Equivalent],
[Nama C Boreholes].[Elevation],
([Nama C Boreholes].[Elevation]-[Analysis].[Depth]) as [Sample_Elevation]
from
[Analysis]
inner join [Nama C Boreholes]
on [Analysis].[Project]=[Nama C Boreholes].[Project]
and [Analysis].[Borehole]=[Nama C Boreholes].[Borehole]
```

Comment: Kindly show me your two tables with sample values so we can visualize where you got the column type mismatch.

Comment: What data type is `ASCo`?  If it's varchar, you could receive that error...